# ActionScript 3 Error 1009. Basic coding really

Tags: actionscript-3

So I'm writing a really basic app for an app dev class but I'm a designer than a developer so bear with me on this.

It involves using Caurina tweeners just moving stuff around.

```
import caurina.transitions.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
stop();trace(fab_mc);

//Scene 2 Nav Scripts
//fab 1&2
fab_mc.fab2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fab2);
function fab2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Tweener.addTween(fab_mc,{x:-637.4,time:1,transition:"easeInOutQuart"});

}

fab_mc.fab1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fab1);
function fab1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Tweener.addTween(fab_mc,{x:-136.70,time:1,transition:"easeInOutQuart"});

}
```

It blows up (according to the debugger ) at line 7 due to "fab_mc" being apparently null. Frankly, I had no idea what a null is about until just this morning - I wrote the code yesterday, it worked fine.

But when I added some more content and coded it, it started complaining. The code for is essentially a lot of tweeners. Sorry if I'm not providing a lot of info, but it's all I have really.

Error code:

```
null
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Arafabricator_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()[Arafabricator_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:7]
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
    at Arafabricator_fla::fab_mc_10()
    at flash.display::MovieClip/nextScene()
    at Arafabricator_fla::MainTimeline/menu07()[Arafabricator_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:64]
```

Comment: The problem is what you said: `fab_mc` is null (thus not a MovieClip). And as it's null, it clearly won't have a  `fab2_btn` property to add an event listener to. Maybe make sure that on that frame you actually have a MovieClip with a `fab_mc` instance name?

Comment: It is a movieclip since birth. Uhh, no idea how/when it turned null. 

And buttons such as "fab2_btn" are nested inside the movie clip named "fab_mc". 

There is only one frame in the entire scene. The nested buttons essentially move the movie clip around the stage.

Answer (score 0):

If `fab_mc` is `null` it means it does not exist on the frame that you have that code. Just make sure you put that code on a frame where the `fab_mc` symbol also exists. You can't, for example, put that code on frame 1 but the symbol first exists on a keyframe on frame 5. In that case put the code on a keyframe on frame 5 as well.